# INotifyPropertyChanging could not be found

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I have a Windows Phone app, upgraded to 7.1, and I used sqlite2ce tool to generate the code to convert my sqlite database to SQL Server. However, the code generated contains mentions to `INotifyPropertyChanging`, and I have error about that. The type cannot be found in `System.ComponentModel`, but in the demo project it can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanging%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) `INotifyPropertyChanging` is in `mscorlib.Extensions.dll` rather than `mscorlib.dll`.

So make sure you have that assembly referenced as well.